# Crop rectangle in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIohg.jpg)

and I want to crop each book from the shelf. I started it with this code.

```
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)

cv2.imshow("Gray", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("Blurred", blur)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# detect edges in the image
edged = cv2.Canny(img, 10, 250)
cv2.imshow("Edged", edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# construct and apply a closing kernel to 'close' gaps between 'white'
# pixels
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 6))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("Closed", closed)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# loop over the contours
for contour in contours:

    # peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    # approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.02 * peri, True)
    # r = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if len(contour) >= 4:
        index += 1
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        # cv2.imwrite("a/" + "book - " + str(index) + '.jpg', roi)
        draw_contour = cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (255, 140, 240), 2)
        total += 1

print contour

cv2.imshow("Drawed Contour", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I created a bounding box in each of the books from the shelf, but unfortunately this gives me the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3gsY.jpg). I want only to draw a bounding box in the side/corner of the books and then crop it from the bounding box.

Comment: I would use hough transform to detect rectangles and then filter by orientation  and size. I dont think a simple edge detector will work in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can explicitly identify only books with this code but one quick improvement you can do in code is to draw contours which have area greater than some value. Following code snippet

```
 if len(contour) >= 4:
    index += 1
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # cv2.imwrite("a/" + "book - " + str(index) + '.jpg', roi)
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 200:
        draw_contour = cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (255, 140, 240), 2)
        total += 1
```

Comment: I will apply your suggestion. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thanks @Nilay its working. But I did some adjustments for larger book spines, like for example a dictionary. Again, thanks!

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. If you still have the code, can you please share the adjustments you made? (Perhaps as an edit to the original question)